# SQL Exception in dynamic sql

Tags: sql, exception, transactions

I'm baffled and frustrated, so is 2 of my peers... I have a stored procedure that starts a transaction, does number of things (including a number of dynamic SQL statements) but as soon as it gets to the statement below it bombs out with an exception. If however I hardcode the statement it executes successfully.

It also does not step into it's own try block, it immediately bombs out to the try block in the calling stored procedure with the following error:

> Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of
>   BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 0, current count = 1.

Please let me know if I'm missing something...

```
SET @SQL = N'UPDATE PF205.dbo.SOP30200 SET ECTRX = 4 WHERE SOPNUMBE = @SOPNUMBE AND SOPTYPE = 4'
        SET @PARAMDEF = N'@SOPNUMBE CHAR(21)';      

        BEGIN TRY
            EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL,
            @PARAMDEF,
            @SOPNUMBE = @SOPNUMBE
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            SELECT ERROR_NUMBER(),
                ERROR_MESSAGE() 
        END CATCH
```

Comment: I should mention that there are 2 triggers on the table but I have disabled both

Comment: Ok, please ignore this, its a looooong story....